# Nuget package referenced library has different names on Linux and Windows

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, sharppcap

I am working on small packet sniffer which will run on Windows and Linux. For sniffing packets I use SharpPcap. SharpPcap runs with no problems on Windows. On Linux there are some tweaks which are needed to be done to make everything working fine since Linux is not using Wpcap.dll but Libpcap.so and I am getting error/exception because **wpcap** dll/so was not found. Those tweaks depend on Framework I chose for project.

## Linux(Ubuntu 18.04):

I installed libpcap with apt-get install libpcap-dev.

### 1. .NET Framework 4.6.1

Mapping **wpcap** to **libpacap** in SharpPcap.dll.config must be done. Then Running MyProject.exe with mono threws no exception and everything works fine.

### 2. .NET Core 2.1 project.

Library **libpcap.so** needs to be renamed **wpcap.so** then 'dotnet run' command runs project without problems and everything works fine.

In both approaches everything seems to be working fine but something doesn't feel right about their background. I am new in this kind of issues. Could you please help me to chose between those two or help me find some other way to make nuget package sharppcap working on both Linux and Windows?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "package"? Installers?

Comment: I meant Shappcap nuget package. Sorry I could write it more clear. I edited question.

Comment: It should be the responsibilities of SharpPcap's authors to map to different native libraries on different platforms. You might report this issue to them or propose a pull request. Changing the name of of library (libpcap.so to wpcap.so) is clearly not the right way.

Comment: I sent them a pull request, https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap/pull/61 and once that's merged you should not need to do anything special on Linux.

Comment: Whole time I believed in better solution that two I found.  Thank you very much for your help @LexLi. I will remember this approach you showed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library was updated and now works fine with Linux.